# On finding a second countable basis for the tangent bundle $TM$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $M$ be a manifold. I want to show that the tangent bundle $TM$ is second countable.

I know that for a given chart $(U, \phi)$ on $M$ we have a homeomorphism $D_{\phi}$ between $TU$ and $\phi(U) \times \mathbb{R}^m$. I also know that we can define a Topology on $TM$ via this map.

I want to construct a second countable basis for $TM$.

My attempt:

Let $E$ in $TM$ be open. By definition, this is the case iff for any chart $(U, \phi)$ of $M$,  $D_{\phi} (E \cap TU)$ is open in $\phi(U) \times \mathbb{R}^m$. Since $\phi(U) \times \mathbb{R}^m$ is second countable it admits a countable Basis $B_{\phi}$. Then, since $D_{\phi}$ is a homeomorphism we have $E \cap TU= \bigcup_{B \in B_{\phi}, \ \  (D_{\phi})^{-1}(B) \subset E \cap TU} (D_{\phi})^{-1} (B)$. Now since $E$ is the union of $E \cap TU$ over all charts $(U,\phi)$ of $M$ I'm tempted to define the following basis of $TM$ : $B'= \{ (D_{\phi})^{-1} (B) | B \in B_{\phi}, \ \ (U, \phi)$ chart of $M \}$, wich i think, is countable since the set of charts on $M$ is countable ($M$ beeing second countable) and $B_{\phi}$ is countable, for each of those charts.

Does this make sense? Could you help me find a second countable basis?

Comment: That sounds fine, because there is a general theorem that a countable union of countable sets is countable, and that explains why your $B'$ is countable. However, logicians might chime in and remind us that this general theorem uses the axiom of choice in its proof. In which case I believe that you can give a more constructive and explicit enumeration of your set $B'$.

Comment: @LeeMosher thanks for your time. My concern was more on  $B'$ beeing  a basis, then the fact that it is countable (wich follows from the theorem you mentioned). Do you think it works?